# What is Enlightenment, according to Robert Wright?

Tags: enlightenment, psychology

Robert Wright had a [course about relations between Buddhism and modern psychology](https://www.coursera.org/course/psychbuddhism). I didn't have chance to watch the whole course, and I'm wondering how he sees enlightenment from that perspective. I hope I can get an answer from someone who attended the course or knows Robert Wright's take on enlightenment from other sources.

Comment: I've read Paul Bloom's review of the '"Evolution of God" by Robert Wright, though he says it's a brilliant book. His thinking is inconsistent, contradicting himself as he argues as an agnostic. >  In Bloom's word "he argues, religions like Buddhism have sometimes “outperformed the Abrahamics.” But this sounds like the death of God, not his evolution."  I quote " Also, it would be a terribly minimalist God. Wright himself describes it as “somewhere between illusion and imperfect conception.” ". How do you make out someone's view if they are inconsistent in their thinking.

Comment: To know if somebody is inconsistent, we need to know what he says. So far nobody has provided any answer about what Wright says about the Enlightenment, so discussing its possible inconsistency is pointless.

Comment: When this class was originally offered, I took it.  Sorry to say, but I may not have watched those videos, as I don't remember what he said.  However, an email just came into my mailbox; the course has now been made available in "on-demand" mode, so you can watch the videos yourself to see what he said: https://www.coursera.org/learn/science-of-meditation

Comment: Your question gave rise to an interest in this course which I began today, finishing week one. Enlightenment is covered in weeks three. I will pay special attention and get back to you regarding your question.

Answer (score 2):

I took this course and my feeling is that Robert Wright is more into about asking questions rather than giving answers. At most he would give you potential answers, but it's up to you to decide for yourself what is "the answer".